# How to create Matrix from 3 coordinate arrays in Matlab/R?

Tags: arrays, r, matlab, coordinates

This is old problem but yet I am not able to fix this issue in my code.
I have 3 arrays:
x, y, z each are column vectors of size N. x, y are coordinates data and z is the value measured at each point. Now what I want is to have a matrix of N by N corresponding to the value of each point.
This is the sample data [x y z]:

```
1467713 599153  17.91
1468244 599296  17.91
1468776 599439  61.90
1469307 599582  17.91
1469838 599725  17.91
1470369 599868  38.23
1470900 600011  17.91
1471431 600154  43.41
1471962 600296  23.73
1472493 600439  21.80
1473024 600582  17.91
1473556 600725  17.91
1474087 600868  23.95
1474618 601011  17.91
1475149 601154  60.15
1475680 601297  17.91
1476211 601440  94.47
1476742 601583  37.72
1477273 601725  17.91
```

P.s. my data is unorganized collection of of lat longs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the (Matlab) solution that you are looking for may be:

```
H = NaN(max(x),max(y))
for i = 1:length(x)
   H(x(i),y(i)) = z(i)
end
```

I used `NaN` so that the matrix between measured points would be 'empty'. You can ofcourse also initialize with something like `zeros`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but why max(x),max(y)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Suppose I make it 10x10, and one point is located at (11,1), then that point will not fit in the matrix when I try to assign it.
Note that if you think the field is too big, you can cut off the unused parts afterwards or reduce all `x` and `y` coordinates with `min(x)-1` and `min(y)-1` respectively.

Comment: OK,I have a problem here. the size of each one of my column arrays are 6,581. when I run your code, it gives me error on Out of Memory.

Comment: @Amir Assuming your coordinates do not start at zero, it should be solved by adjusting the x and y coordinates as I described in my previous comment. If you do not care about NaN, then it is more easily solved by initializing like so: `H = sparse(max(x),max(y))`

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized alternative:

```
m = max(x);
n = max(y);
ind = sub2ind([m,n], x, y);
I(ind) = z;
```

You could also initialize I as in Dennis' answer if you prefer `NaN` to `0` for the missing pixels.